# Why is $-1$ not THE only real root of $f(x)=x^3+x+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Here is what I thought.

1. By the Descartes' Rule of Signs, $f(x)=x^3+x+1$ has no change in signs so it has no positive real root, and $f(-x)=-x^3-x+1$ has only one change in signs so it has exactly one negative real root.
2. Furthermore, because $f(x)$ is a rational polynomial, all its irrational roots appear in conjugate pairs and so its complex roots if there is any. Therefore the only negative real root can not be irrational or complex, which means it must be a negative rational root.
3. Then by the rational root test, all rational must be either $1$ or $-1$ if there is any. Hence $-1$ should be the only negative real root.

May anyone tell me where I was wrong because obvioulsy $f(-1)\ne 0$...?

Comment: “All it’s irrational roots come in conjugate pairs.” This is not true. It is true that all complex roots come in conjugate pairs, but real irrational roots do no necessarily come in pairs.

Comment: $-1$ is not the *only* real root, *because* it is *not a* root to the equation.  The only real root would be approximately $-0.68233...$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I remembered that the irrational roots of a rational polynomial come in pairs. It is not?

Comment: This is a counterexample to what you remembered.

Comment: @RobertIsrael haha so true but is it true that if all the complex roots of a rational polynomial are real, then the irrational roots must come in pairs?

Comment: It is only the non-real complex roots that must come in pairs.

Comment: @AndyZ "*irrational roots must come in pairs*" $\;-\;$ That's true for quadratics with rational coefficients, and for square roots by [The radical conjugate roots theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2444227/the-radical-conjugate-roots-theorem), but neither applies here.

Comment: @dxiv Alright, it must be me that misremembered this. Thanks a lot.